# How to split a text into characters and get a text including every nth character ? (Maybe in Excel)

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, office365

Here's the problem: I have a text and I want it to be represented as separate texts that is made by characters mod n. For example text: "hfhshsseekbfe...", n=5, then first one "hsb..." (1st,6th,11th character from the original), second one "fsf..." (2nd,7th,12th character from the original) and so on. It will be simpler to write a program in cpp that reads and extracts needed information (modulo n characters) from a file and writes it down in a new .txt file. But I'm not a coder, I did some of coding for my Numerical Analysis course, but there wasn't any strings. So maybe Excel have some algorithms to do it?

Comment: You question is not so clear. Can you make and full example like input few data to a sheet then show expected output. Your example `n=5, then first one "hsb..."` means what?

Comment: @Harun24HR , I've edited my question.

Comment: @bheardr 73, Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel sheet, with <kbd>ExcelO365</kbd> you can use `Sequence()` formula with `MID()` function like-

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),,1,5),1))
```

[image]

For second one just make `Start Number` parameter of `Sequence()` formula to `2` like

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),,2,5),1))
```

Comment: Excel don't accept it as a formula. I have Excel Ofice360.

Comment: Then your excel doesn't have access to dynamic formulas. Just for testing, can you try it to excel web version?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked in my Excel, like this =TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;MID(A1;SEQUENCE(LEN(A1);;1;5);1))

Comment: Comma `(,)` and semicolon `(;)` depends on regional settings. If it works then please consider accepting the answer (Tick mark it).